# Ubuntu postgresql 2 databas in two hard disks

Tags: postgresql-9.3, migration, ubuntu

I have two postgresql database in single 1tb hard disk. Each data base sizes more than 300gb. So now I faced a disk space problem and I bought another 1tb hard disk recently. So I need to move one database into this new hard disk. How can I do that in Ubuntu ????

If I move one database to another drive, postgresql can communicate both harddisks at same time? Can I access both databases in postgresql on master hard.

Sorry for my bad English.

Answer (score 0):

PostgreSQL has no problem with the data on 2 hard-disks. The best thing that you can do is create a tablespace on your second hard-disk and move one of the databases to this tablespace.

```
CREATE TABLESPACE somename LOCATION 'directory-on-new-disk';
ALTER DATABASE name SET TABLESPACE somename;
```

Also see this post: [Postgresql: Move database to new tablespace](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/11851/postgresql-move-database-to-new-tablespace).

If you use LVM then you can also consider to use this to extend the logical volume on which your database is.

Comment: ALTER DATABASE name SET TABLESPACE somename;  what is this command

Comment: Check the post that I have put in my reply. There the command is explained.